# Will my prestige points reset if I use them before completing the maximum objective cap?

Tags: sky-force-reloaded

The new version has brought a new achievement (technician) mechanism called "objectives". All objectives have 3 stages which correspond to increasing prestige points. What will happen to my achieved stage in one objective if I use it to acquire the next technician without completing the objective's maximum stage? Will they reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect the points, they will not reset.